# Что такое псевдо массив/объект?

Tags: javascript, массивы, faq

Например есть такой объект как `arguments` доступный внутри любой функции.

1. В текстах его называют псевдо-массив, а не просто массив.
2. Из него не получается сделать JSON строку.

Пожалуйста объясните два этих пункта.

Comment: А тут https://learn.javascript.ru/arguments-pseudoarray разве плохо написано?

Comment: там написано 
> Такие объекты иногда называют «коллекциями» или «псевдомассивами».

но парадокс в том что массив в других языках не может принимать разные элементы (т.е не может иметь свойства например). а в JS можно проделать такое `var arr = []; arr.test = 1;` тогда можно смело утверждать что все подобные конструкции это псевдо-массивы, а настоящих массивов нет.

Comment: `arguments` это массив аргументов функции, а `arr.test = 1;` - свойство объекта. `var arr= {};` - объект и ассоциативный массив в тоже время.

Comment: @Visman, `arguments` это не массив аргументов функции, это обычный объект, у которого есть свойсто `length`.

Comment: @saaaaaaaaasha, от этого он не прекращает содержать в себе массив аргументов функции :Р

Comment: @Visman он содержит в себе просто аргументы функции, а не массив

Comment: @PavelMayorov, нет, я вам не верю. `просто аргументы функции` это и есть `массив аргуметов`.

Comment: @Visman проверим? https://jsfiddle.net/kaqe6auy/1/

Comment: @PavelMayorov, `TypeError: document.body.append is not a function`

Comment: @Visman Пользователь IE детектед! https://jsfiddle.net/kaqe6auy/2/

Comment: @PavelMayorov, не IE, а FF. И ваш пример не противоречит моему комментарию `от этого он не прекращает содержать в себе массив аргументов функции`.

Comment: @Visman FF поддерживает append с версии 49.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, 49 версия тормозная и глючная.

Comment: @Visman так же как все остальные xD

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Псевдомассив - это объект, структура которого совпадает со структурой массива (т.е. он хранит элементы в индексах от 0 до length-1), но при этом он не обладает методами, свойственными полноценным массивам из-за отличий в прототипе.

Сделать свой псевдомассив довольно просто:

```
var a = {0 : 'foo', 1: 'bar', length: 2};
```

Теперь `a` - псевдомассив из 2х элементов. К ним можно обращаться по индексам - `a[0]`, `a[1]` - но у него нет таких методов как `sort`, `slice`, `concat`, `forEach`. JSON-сериализатор также сериализует его не как массив, а как объект.

В стандартной библиотеке javascript единственным классом псевдомассивов является Arguments, который представлен специальным объектом arguments в каждой регулярной функции.

Также в браузерном javascript псевдомассивами являются экземпляры классов NodeList, HTMLCollection и подобных, возвращаемые некоторыми функциями для работы с DOM, такими как `document.getElementsByXXX()`.

Любую функцию, работающую с массивом, можно применить к псевдомассиву при помощи call:

```
a.sort(); // Ошибка: в псевдомассиве нет метода sort
Array.prototype.sort.call(a); // А вот так - работает
[].sort.call(a); // И так тоже работает
```

Также псевдомассив можно превратить в нормальный массив при помощи [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) или [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(a); // ["foo", "bar"]
Array.from(a); // ["foo", "bar"]
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48459/discussion-on-answer-by-pavel-mayorov-----).

Comment: `Array.from` забыл :)

Comment: @Grundy спасибо

Comment: Если вы не против, я бы предложил добавить функцию для проверки: является ли объект псевдомассивом. https://jsfiddle.net/yuri_spivak/8tjLmeut/

Comment: @Yuri в вашей "строгой" проверке мало смысла, потому что нечисловые ключи могут и у настоящего массива быть.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, всё, я понял. псевдомассивом является объект, у которого есть свойство `length` и он равен целому положительному числу